# Unexpected 401.5 error. Authentication header changed to Kerberos?

Tags: soap, authorization, webclient, trace

This problem seems to exist on a specific server. All other servers are working ok.

Background: The website is basically Forms Auth but there's an asmx that manually requires Basic Auth.

I have two C# client.

1. When invoking using SOAP (asmx client proxy) with basic auth credentials - all is well.
2. When invoking using WebClient or WebRequest with the same basic auth credentials, I get 401.5.
3. The folders have "Everyone" set to them.

When setting up iis trace, I see a very weird behavior. The request arrives with the correct Basic auth header. But further down the trace I see the following:

GENERAL_REQUEST_HEADERS

Headers="Connection: Keep-Alive
Content-Length: 68
Content-Type: application/json
**Authorization: Kerberos**
Expect: 100-continue
Host: 1.2.3.4

The Kerberos seems very weird. It is as if the request headers changed throughout the process, and perhaps that explains the 401.5.

Again, I would like to stress out that on other servers there's no problem with both clients. The only difference I can think of is that the problematic server is a DC. But if that is a problem then why is the SOAP client working well?

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Progress!

After some debugging I noticed that Application_AuthenticateRequest was fired twice for every request. The first time with Basic auth as I expected and the second time with the Kerberos!

After googling I found this:

http://forums.asp.net/t/1868629.aspx?HttpModule+triggered+two+times+for+request+to+URL+without+default+document

Seems like for extensionless urls those events might fire multiple times, depending on the configured Extensionless urls.

Going back to the trace I noticed that in the non-working server the trace shows usage of ExtensionlessUrl-ISAPI-4.0_64bit, and in the working servers no such entry existed. After comparing the two IIS I noticed that the non-working IIS had ExtensionlessUrl-ISAPI-4.0_64bit configured whereas in the working IIS there was ExtensionlessUrl**Handler**-ISAPI-4.0_64bit (note the "handler"). I compared the dlls involved and the working server had a newer aspnet_isapi.dll. I assume that this is an updated extensionless url handler. I suppose an upgrade to IIS or .NET might install a later version, but for now I tried to remove the ExtensionlessUrl-ISAPI-4.0_xxbit like so:

```
    <remove name="ExtensionlessUrl-ISAPI-4.0_32bit" />
    <remove name="ExtensionlessUrl-ISAPI-4.0_64bit" />
```

And it worked! Now there is only a single Application_AuthenticateRequest.

The non-working version that had this in the trace:

OldHandlerName="", NewHandlerName="ExtensionlessUrl-ISAPI-4.0_64bit", NewHandlerModules="IsapiModule", NewHandlerScriptProcessor="C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\aspnet_isapi.dll", NewHandlerType=""

Now changed to:

OldHandlerName="", NewHandlerName="WebServiceHandlerFactory-ISAPI-4.0_64bit", NewHandlerModules="IsapiModule", NewHandlerScriptProcessor="C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\aspnet_isapi.dll", NewHandlerType=""

Hopefully that's the end of it. Additional testing still required.

I would appreciate if someone can write how to upgrade IIS dlls to a later version. Is this an upgrade to .NET or is there a specific KB update that is downloaded with Windows Update?